# Dynamically creating a component renders as a sibling

Tags: angular

A component `about-me` is created dynamically and injected in a `div` but the component is not rendered inside the `div` tag instead rendered as a sibling. How to render the dynamically created component inside the `div` tag.

**Code:**

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="card-content" #sectionContainer></div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
...
@ViewChild('sectionContainer', {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) sectionEntry: ViewContainerRef;
...
  loadAboutMeComponent() {
    this.store.dispatch(new OpenSection());
    this.sectionEntry.clear();
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AboutmeComponent);
    const componentRef = this.sectionEntry.createComponent(factory);
  }
```

Console:

[image]

The component is rendering perfectly fine, but not inside the div. May i know why?

Comment: There was a historical reason https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8529#issuecomment-217718704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening in your code is that by using `{ read: ViewContainerRef }` on a `div` element you are basically transforming it into a `ViewContainer` which, as its name implies, it is **just** a **container** for **other views**. A `ViewContainer` it is **not** rendered on the page, it just displays the views that it contains.

You can read more about **host views**, **embedded views** and `ViewContainer`'s API [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866).

*[Here is the TLDR](https://stackblitz.com/edit/working-with-the-dom) for the aforementioned article*.

Of course, any element can server as a `ViewContainer`, but usually you would want to use `<ng-container #viewcontainer></ng-container>`.

So, if you want your component to be rendered inside the div, you'd have to do this:

```html
<div class="card-content">
 <ng-container #sectionContainer></ng-container>
</div>
```